# How to use Entity Metadata wrappers for fields of a bundle?

Tags: entities

I am not able to access the fields of a bundle using entity metadata wrappers.Here is what I am doing.

```
//Entity Obj is the loaded entity object which contains a bundle whose fields I am trying to access
$entity_obj; 
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('theentitytype',$entity_obj,array('bundle'=>'thebundlename'));
```

But I am not able to see the fields of the bundle after doing this.The metadata wrapper function says the bundle_type should be mentioned as key = 'bundle' and value='bundle_name' inside of an array like which I am doing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "see the fields" exactly? Fields and properties are only discoverable by magic methods on an metadata wrapper so are you saying `$wrapper->getPropertyInfo()` is empty? Or perhaps you just weren't aware of the magic methods and getting confused because you don't see fields when you `var_dump' the object?

Comment: Well kind of both confused and I am not able to see the fields when doing getPropertyInfo().I can see that I need to get one level further from the entity to the bundle and then get the fields of it, which I am unable to do.

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong then, this works fine for me: `entity_metadata_wrapper('node', NULL, array('bundle' => 'article'))->getPropertyInfo()`. That array contains the expected fields. Did you read this part of the docs for `bundle`? _If an entity is wrapped but not passed, use this key to specify the bundle to return a wrapper for._ If you have a loaded entity object you shouldn't use that property